# template issue with class derived from const

Tags: c++

Given following code:

```
class MyClass {};
template< class T > class Base {};
template< class T > class Derived : public Base< const T > {};

Base< const MyClass* >* MyFunc ()
{
    return new Derived< MyClass* >();
}
```

clang gives:

```
error: cannot initialize return object of type 'Base<const MyClass *> *' with an rvalue of type 'Derived<MyClass *> *'
```

However, "Derived MyClass*" is derived from "Base const MyClass*", so I expected it to work.
What did I get wrong ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because `Derived<MyClass*>` is derived from `Base<MyClass* const>`, *not* `Base<const MyClass*>`. The former means a `const` pointer to `MyClass`, the latter means a pointer to a `const MyClass`.

You need to think about what you want to be `const`: the pointer or the pointee.

If it's the pointer, then just change the return type to `Base<MyClass* const>`*.

If it's the pointee, then you'll need to do some transformations on `T` in your definition for `Derived`. If you only expect `T` to be a pointer, then `const std::remove_pointer_t<T>*` will probably work for you, otherwise you'll need to do some partial specialization.

Comment: Thanks. Fixed using 
"class Derived : public Base< const typename std::remove_pointer<T>::type* >" since remove_pointer_t is C++14.

Answer (score 2):

`Derived< MyClass* >` is derived from `Base<MyClass * const>`.
Note what becomes `const` here, since `T` is not `MyClass`, but `MyClass*`

If you want to force the `const` to be applied to the pointee when `T` is a pointer type, you need to make use of a helper template & some meta-programming.

Answer (score 0):

The source of confusion:

```
const MyClass* ptr;  // ptr is is a non-const pointer to a const object
MyClass* const ptr;  // ptr is a const pointer to a non-const object.
```

Hence, you need to use:

```
Base< MyClass const* >* MyFunc ()
{
    return new Derived< MyClass* >();
}
```